# How to use ! in mentioned query?

Tags: sql

I have data in below format

('CA-2014-118892', '8/18/2014', 'Tom Prescott', 'Furniture', 'Chairs', 4416.174, -630.882),

('US-2012-163825', '6/16/2012', 'Lena Creighton', 'Office Supplies', 'Binders', 3050.376, 1143.891),

('CA-2012-114811', '11/8/2012', 'Keith Dawkins', 'Technology', 'Machines', 4643.8, 2229.024)

Now when i try to use wildcard [!T]% on third value/column which is name, I was hoping it would give me the other two(Lena and Keith). Instead it is showing me the entry from customer 'Tom'.

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERDATA
(
    Ord_ID CHAR(15),
    Ord_date DATE NULL,
    Cust_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Category CHAR(20) NULL,
    Sub_C CHAR(20) Null,
    Sales INT NOT NULL,
    Profit INT NOT NULL
)

SELECT * FROM ORDERDATA WHERE Cust_name LIKE '[!T]%'
```

I dropped the table and re added values just to be sure it was not some run error but this error persists.

Comment: What _version_ of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual implementation.

Comment: What exact SQL statement are you executing?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Sever 2014

Comment: @kmoser I have written above the exact code i am running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve all records whose customer names do *not* begin with `T`, then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDERDATA
WHERE Cust_name NOT LIKE 'T%';
```

If instead you want all customer names which do not contain `T` anywhere, then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDERDATA
WHERE Cust_name NOT LIKE '%T%';
```

If `LIKE` be case sensitive on your database, then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDERDATA
WHERE LOWER(Cust_name) NOT LIKE 't%';
```

**Edit:**

On SQL Server, you could also phrase your `LIKE` expression using the extended regex syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDERDATA
WHERE Cust_name LIKE '[^T]%';
```

Note that negating a `T` is done using `^`, not `!`, the latter which has no special meaning with `LIKE`.

Comment: I actually wanted to use " ! " in the query and wanted to know why it was not working

Comment: @VinamraBali Check my updated answer.  I think you were intending to use `WHERE Cust_name LIKE '[^T]%'`

Comment: @VinamraBali more details in Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: This still shows me names which start with T , I want every name which does not start with T. Below some one has advised me to use 'NOT LIKE' but i was wondering if i could use ' ! ' instead of 'NOT LIKE'.

Comment: @VinamraBali My answer in fact [is working in this demo](https://rextester.com/WKAD63326), using your sample data.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen. I did not remove "not" with my "like" earlier. This is working :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want these that do not *start* with 'T':

```
select * from ORDERDATA where Cust_name not like 'T%'
```

Otherwise it may be:

```
select * from ORDERDATA where Cust_name not like '%T%'
```

NOTE: Beware upper/lower if you need to match both, conversion is db specific

Comment: I actually wanted to use " ! " in the query and wanted to know why it was not working

Comment: That is supported in SQL unless you want to use regular expression, in this case it is db specific